# Please look at the following code. Code is running fine. output is [10,11]. What is the meaning of line final A a = new A();

Tags: java, oop, static, final

Please have a look at following code:

```
public class Test 
    {
        public static void main(String[] s)
        {
            final A a = new A(); // What is the meaning of this line ?
            System.out.println(a.count);
            a.count = 11;
            System.out.println(a.count);
        }
    }

    class A 
    {
        int count = 10;
    }
```

What is the meaning of line **final A a = new A();** when can we use this?

Comment: Creating an instance of class `a`...

Comment: @chandresh what you don't undestand ? `final` ,  `new A()`  or both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you declare and initialize a variable (no matter whether it is primitive or reference type) with the `final` keyword you can never reinitialize it. That means after this statement -

```
final A a = new A();
```

You can never assign `a` to a new reference like this -

```
a = new A(); //another instance/object of `A` is created
```

But if you declare a `no-final` variable `anotherA`, then you can reassign it -

A anotherA = new A(); //declaration and initialization
anotherA = new A(); //reassign `anotherA` to a new instance/object of type `A`

Answer (score 3):

The line creates an instance of class `A` and assigns it to variable `a`. The `final` means the variable cannot be reassigned.

So you can use `final` when you don't reassign the variable. For example, the following code raises compilation error:

```
final A a = new A();
a = new A(); // reassignment causes error
```

Answer (score 0):

The `final` keyword also enforce you to initialize a variable while it is declaring. If you try to write something like this -

```
final A a ; //only declare not initialized
```

Then you will get a compilation error.

Comment: You can have a `final` that is initialized in the constructor as well.